# How to I find those id who have login to the game mroe than 1 times a day?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, count, where-clause

Let say we have a table like below

```
    day     | username |  game    |  
------------+----------+----------+
 2016-08-06 |    1     | game_A   | 
 2016-08-06 |    1     | game_B   | 
 2016-08-08 |    1     | game_A   | 
 2016-08-10 |    1     | game_C   |
 2016-08-18 |    2     | game_C   | 
 2016-09-18 |    2     | game_A   | 
 2016-09-18 |    2     | game_C   | 
 2016-10-18 |    2     | game_B   | 
 2016-09-20 |    3     | game_C   | 
 2016-09-22 |    3     | game_B   |
```

You can think it like Steam like there is a lot of game in Steam, right?. We want to track if the user have played more than 1 game in Steam.

The result table should be

```
    day     | username |  game    |  
------------+----------+----------+
 2016-08-06 |    1     | game_A   | 
 2016-08-06 |    1     | game_B   | 
 2016-09-18 |    2     | game_A   | 
 2016-09-18 |    2     | game_C   |
```

The reason that it output this table is that you can clearly see that username 1 played game_A and game_B on the same day. same with user 2
The code that I wrote

```
select day, username, v
from
(
    select day, username, count(*) as v
    from table
    group by day, username
) as visit
where v > 1
order by day, login

The result:
    day     | username |    v     |  
------------+----------+----------+
 2016-08-06 |    1     |    2     |  
 2016-09-18 |    2     |    2     |
```

I was able to pick the day and username, but how exactly do I split them so that it prints the game as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over(partition by day, username) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: this is good, but I do not want to print out the count(*). I only want to print out the day, username and game. Is it possible to do?

Comment: @user38543: just change `select *` in the outer query and enumerate the columns you want... `select day, username, game from (...) t where cnt > 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.day = t.day and t2.username = t.username and
                    t2.game <> t.game
             );
```

Note:  This interprets "more than one game" as at least two different values of `game` on the same day for the same user.